# What's mongodb's proj.$slice equivalent in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In mongo we can do something like as follows in order to select first or last `count` elements:

The document looks like as follows:

```
{
    id: 123,
    aliases: [
        {name: john}
        {name: alpha}
        {name: tom}
        {name: alpha}
    ]
}
```

You can query in mongo and also restrict the number of `aliases` you want to retrieve from the database as follows:

```
db.collection.find( { field: value }, { array: {$slice: count } } );
```

where,

```
count = 3
```

Is there anything straightforward way to achieve the same result in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent available on DynamoDB. In fact, there is no near equivalent as well.

DynamoDB has a feature to **limit the items on evaluation process**. However, it is **not** equivalent to limiting the number of items in the result set.

> Limit — (Integer)
>
> The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of
>   matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the
>   limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns
>   the matching values up to that point, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation, so that you can pick up where you
>   left off. Also, if the processed data set size exceeds 1 MB before
>   DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the operation and returns the
>   matching values up to the limit, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation to continue the operation. For more
>   information, see Query and Scan in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer
>   Guide.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. I should have been more clear. I've updated the description of the question for clear understanding.